# VirtualBox machine started after BlueStacks had been run causes OSX to crash

Tags: macos, virtualbox, crash, bluestacks

OSX (Yosemite, El Capitan) crashes and restarts every time I try to:

1) start a machine VirtualBox (5.0.6) and BlueStacks concurrently (no matter which is started first)

2) run BlueStacks, close BlueStacks, start any virtual machine in VirtualBox

VirtualBox machines run normally only if BlueStacks had not been started after last reboot. And BlueStacks starts if VirtualBox was closed before. So direct reason for system crash seems to be VirtualBox, while the cause seems to be BlueStacks (I understand that BlueStacks uses VirtualBox components)

I don't necessarily need to run them concurrently, but would be happy if the VirtualBox did not cause system to crash.

Can I (and how) close BlueStacks so that no "leftovers" remain?

Answer (score 1):

I found this reply from VirtualBox users:

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=74118

> xactly. And we can do absolutely nothing about it. BlueStacks uses VirtualBox code without any attempt to coordinate with Oracle (which they certainly are allowed to do under the terms of the GPL). It is unfortunate that they mess up existing VirtualBox installs.
>
> It is generally not possible to have two different VirtualBox versions installed on a system, unfortunately that is what BlueStacks effectively does. If this is a problem for you, please contact BlueStacks as Oracle has no relationship with them.

Comment: First: it is a response to my question. Second: it does not provide an answer to the question: how to deal with the problem (clean up after BlueStacks). Altogether it should be a comment.

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry!